# HTMX - how to conditionally set target and swap?

Tags: javascript, htmx

I have a datatable and add item form which shows as a modal ( bootstrap ) I'm using htmx to add an entry and swap the datatable with latest data.

Now, I want to handle things like validation and errors.

How to approach this problem, I want to close modal and show updated table if request was successful, or I want to keep the modal and show form with error messages on modal.

Can i conditionally swap the target ? if xhr.status == 400, swap id_add_form else if xhr.status == 201 modal.close(); swap id_item_list

here is the outline of my code

```html
<!--begin::Card-->
<div class="card" id="user_list_table">
...
    <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#modal_add_item"
                hx-get="/add-item"
                hx-target="#add_user_form"
                hx-swap="innerHTML"
                hx-trigger="click">
    Add Item
    </button>

    <div class="modal">
    <form
        id="add_item_form"
        class="form"
        hx-post="/add-item"
        hx-trigger="submit"
        hx-swap="none"
    >
    ...
    </form>
    </div>
    ...

    <div id="item_list">
    ...
    </div>

...
</div>
```

and js

```js
    document.addEventListener("htmx:afterRequest", function (event) {
    
                if (event.detail.elt == "add_item_form") {
    
                    var form = document.getElementById('add_item_form');
    
                    // if event is 200 ok
                    if (event.detail.xhr.status == 200) {
                        // close modal
                        form.reset();
                        modal.hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to close the modal and update the table at the same time, you will be better off with adding custom event to your response. (ref: https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/) in combination with HX-push-url if you need to change url history.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extention for htmx https://htmx.org/extensions/response-targets/

which allows us to target different elements for different responses.

```html
<button hx-post="/register"
        hx-target="#response-div"
        hx-target-5*="#serious-errors"
        hx-target-404="#not-found">
    Register!
</button>
```

when combining this with javascript, I could make it work

Answer (score -1):

You can listen to a `beforeSwap` event on the form. The [event.detail](https://htmx.org/events/#htmx:configRequest) will have the `shouldSwap` attribute which which can conditionally set.

```
document.getElementById("add_item_form").addEventListener("htmx:beforeSwap", (event)=>{
    // After server validation
    if (event.detail.xhr.status !== 200) {
        event.detail.shouldSwap = false
        // No need to set new target since the form is already the target
        return
  }
   // Else reset form and hide modal
})
```